# Parsing double quoted values in PHP

Tags: php

I have a csv document in the following format

```
"field1" "tom" "david"    "ronald"
```

The pattern delimiting each item is the double quote around them, but not the space separating them, as it can vary.

So explode() won't work and how can I get the double quoted terms in one array?

Comment: Maybe a loop with substr or regular expressions can work for you.

Comment: PHP has it... http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php

Comment: [`var_dump(preg_split('/"\s*"/', $string));`?](https://eval.in/86554)

Comment: Have you tried `fgetcsv` with a space or a `"\t"` as the delimiter?

Comment: str-getcsv does look like what I want by defining enclosure as '"'; however what should be put as delimiter? I tried whitespace but it wouldn't work for more than one space between the terms.

Answer (score 2):

**#1** [explode()](http://php.net/explode)

```
<?php
$row = '"field1" "tom" "david"    "ronald"';
$row = array_values(array_filter(array_map("trim", explode('"', $row))));
print_r($row);
```

**#2** [str_getcsv()](http://php.net/str_getcsv)

```
<?php
$row = '"field1" "tom" "david"    "ronald"';
$row = array_filter(str_getcsv($row, '"'));
print_r($row);
```

**#3** [preg_match_all()](http://php.net/preg_match_all)

```
<?php
$row = '"field1" "tom" "david"    "ronald"';
$row = preg_match_all('/"([^"]+)"/', $row, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

**Output**:

```
Array
(
    [0] => field1
    [1] => tom
    [2] => david
    [3] => ronald
)
```